# Is this benchmark comparing Java 8u40 and 8u31 for multiplying BigInteger values correct?

Tags: java, performance, biginteger, jmh

I saw that [JDK-8055494 : Add C2 x86 intrinsic for BigInteger::multiplyToLen() method](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8055494) was fixed for 8u40 update, but I didn't expect that it will speed up BigInteger multiplication in 2x - 3x times.

Here are results of benchmarks which calculate factorial by different formulas on both JVM updates:

**8u31**

```
[info] Benchmark                             (n)   Mode  Cnt       Score       Error   Units
[info] JavaFactorial.recursion              1000  thrpt    5      13.994 ±     0.175  ops/ms
[info] JavaFactorial.recursion             10000  thrpt    5       0.202 ±     0.054  ops/ms
[info] JavaFactorial.recursionPar           1000  thrpt    5      12.066 ±     8.011  ops/ms
[info] JavaFactorial.recursionPar          10000  thrpt    5       0.253 ±     0.055  ops/ms
[info] JavaFactorial.split                  1000  thrpt    5      18.255 ±     2.656  ops/ms
[info] JavaFactorial.split                 10000  thrpt    5       0.286 ±     0.063  ops/ms
```

**8u40**

```
[info] Benchmark                             (n)   Mode  Cnt       Score       Error   Units
[info] JavaFactorial.recursion              1000  thrpt    5      33.704 ±     0.445  ops/ms
[info] JavaFactorial.recursion             10000  thrpt    5       0.428 ±     0.199  ops/ms
[info] JavaFactorial.recursionPar           1000  thrpt    5      38.170 ±     0.433  ops/ms
[info] JavaFactorial.recursionPar          10000  thrpt    5       0.557 ±     0.030  ops/ms
[info] JavaFactorial.split                  1000  thrpt    5      46.447 ±    11.582  ops/ms
[info] JavaFactorial.split                 10000  thrpt    5       0.586 ±     0.154  ops/ms
```

Should I expect that this JDK improvement leads to run [my code](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/scala-vs-java/blob/c63543f052620156d076e425bc1483d1a94df480/src/main/java/com/github/plokhotnyuk/scala_vs_java/JavaFactorial.java#L24-L37) faster or is this yet another casual benchmark?

**Edit**

How to verify my findings to prove that such speed up was due that C2 intrinsic?

Code of tested functions:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Warmup(iterations = 3, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Fork(1)
public class JavaFactorial {
    @Param({"10", "100", "1000", "10000"})
    public int n;

    private static ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();

    @Benchmark
    public BigInteger loop() {
        return n > 20 ? loop(1, n) : BigInteger.valueOf(fastLoop(1, n));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public BigInteger recursion() {
        return n > 20 ? recursion(1, n) : BigInteger.valueOf(fastLoop(1, n));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public BigInteger recursionPar() {
        return n > 20 ? recursePar(1, n) : BigInteger.valueOf(fastLoop(1, n));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public BigInteger split() {
        return n > 180 ? split(n) : (n > 20 ? recursion(1, n) : BigInteger.valueOf(fastLoop(1, n)));
    }

    private long fastLoop(final int n1, int n2) {
        long p = n1;
        while (n2 > n1) {
            p = p * n2;
            n2--;
        }
        return p;
    }

    private BigInteger loop(int n1, final int n2) {
        final long l = Long.MAX_VALUE >> (32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n2));
        long p = 1;
        BigInteger r = BigInteger.ONE;
        while (n1 <= n2) {
            if (p <= l) {
                p *= n1;
            } else {
                r = r.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(p));
                p = n1;
            }
            n1++;
        }
        return r.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(p));
    }

    private BigInteger recursion(final int n1, final int n2) {
        if (n2 - n1 < 65) {
            return loop(n1, n2);
        }
        final int nm = (n1 + n2) >> 1;
        return recursion(nm + 1, n2).multiply(recursion(n1, nm));
    }

    private BigInteger recursePar(final int n1, final int n2) {
        if (n2 - n1 < 700) {
            return recursion(n1, n2);
        }
        final int nm = (n1 + n2) >> 1;
        RecursiveTask<BigInteger> t = new RecursiveTask<BigInteger>() {
            protected BigInteger compute() {
                return recursePar(nm + 1, n2);
            }
        };
        if (ForkJoinTask.getPool() == pool) {
            t.fork();
        } else {
            pool.execute(t);
        }
        return recursePar(n1, nm).multiply(t.join());
    }

    private BigInteger loop2(int n1, final int n2) {
        final long l = Long.MAX_VALUE >> (32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n2));
        long p = 1;
        BigInteger r = BigInteger.ONE;
        while (n1 <= n2) {
            if (p <= l) {
                p *= n1;
            } else {
                r = r.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(p));
                p = n1;
            }
            n1 += 2;
        }
        return r.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(p));
    }

    private BigInteger recursion2(final int n1, final int n2) {
        if (n2 - n1 < 65) {
            return loop2(n1, n2);
        }
        final int nm = ((n1 + n2) >> 1) | 1;
        return recursion2(nm, n2).multiply(recursion2(n1, nm - 2));
    }

    private BigInteger split(int n) {
        int i = 31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n), s = -n, o = 1;
        BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE, r = BigInteger.ONE;
        while (i >= 0) {
            int h = n >> i;
            int o1 = (h - 1) | 1;
            if (o < o1) {
                p = p.multiply(recursion2(o + 2, o1));
                r = r.multiply(p);
            }
            o = o1;
            s += h;
            i--;
        }
        return r.shiftLeft(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: not really understand, what is your question / issue?

Comment: Issue will be if my benchmarks are casual and shows speed up due other reason than I tried to test

Comment: What does your error mean? It seems around 2-3x higher too.

Comment: SO should be standalone, shouldn't have to follow a link to get the code in question.

Comment: @weston I see your reasons, but it is hard to show short code & configuration that can reproduce the same result in SO code snippet format.

Comment: I doesn't have to be short, 130 lines isn't that excessive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigation of list of available JVM options I found that one, which was added to 8u40, can switch on/off required intrinsic exactly.

Below are results with `-XX:-UseMultiplyToLenIntrinsic` for 8u40 that are very close to results from 8u31:

```
    [info] JavaFactorial.recursion              1000  thrpt    5      12.521 ±      3.352  ops/ms
    [info] JavaFactorial.recursion             10000  thrpt    5       0.217 ±      0.069  ops/ms
    [info] JavaFactorial.recursionPar           1000  thrpt    5      14.268 ±      8.319  ops/ms
    [info] JavaFactorial.recursionPar          10000  thrpt    5       0.286 ±      0.015  ops/ms
    [info] JavaFactorial.split                  1000  thrpt    5      18.768 ±      4.321  ops/ms
    [info] JavaFactorial.split                 10000  thrpt    5       0.255 ±      0.076  ops/ms
```

Answer (score 1):

This benchmark certainly suggests that any code which makes heavy use of `BigInteger` multiplication would benefit.

The real answer to your question is to write a benchmark test for your own code and run it under both `8u31` and `8u40`. *You* want *your* code to be faster, so benchmark your code and test it. If JRE code or someone elses code is faster that is a sign that your code might benefit but you have to try it and see.

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up of my question!

Comment: Also I'm looking for idea how to verify my findings to prove that such speed up was due that C2 intrinsic.

Comment: I do not see an easy way to isolate the speedup to just the C2 intrinsic. Its possible but you'd have to have a custom java compiler that only has the changes from JDK-8055494.